# CGAL Polyhedron_3 and Nef_polyhedron_3 intersection

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

I am using CGAL for some geometric operations on polyhedrons. In particular I am using the Polyhedron_3 and Nef_polyhedron_3 with the following kernel etc.... :

```
#include "CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h" 
#include "CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h" 
#include "CGAL/Nef_polyhedron_3.h" 
#include "CGAL/Gmpz.h" 
#include "CGAL/Polyhedron_incremental_builder_3.h" 
#include "CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_iostream.h" 

namespace ARECGAL 
{ 
    typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<CGAL::Gmpz> Kernel; 
    typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Polyhedron; 
    typedef CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_3<Kernel> Nef_Polyhedron; 
    typedef Polyhedron::HalfedgeDS HalfedgeDS; 
    typedef Nef_Polyhedron::Vector_3  Vector_3; 
    typedef Nef_Polyhedron::Aff_transformation_3  Aff_transformation_3; 
}
```

And I am performing an intersection using this method:

```
Polyhedron intersection(Polyhedron & i_poly1,Polyhedron & i_poly2) 
{ 
     try 
     { 
         if (i_poly1.is_closed() && i_poly2.is_closed()) 
         { 
              Nef_Polyhedron NP1(i_poly1); 
              Nef_Polyhedron NP2(i_poly2); 
              Nef_Polyhedron NP = NP1 * NP2; 

              //useless code for the topic 
         } 
         else 
         { 
              throw Utils::ProcessControl::AREException(notClosedGeoErrorMsg, 
                                            __FUNCTION__, 
                                            notClosedGeoErrorValue); 
         } 
   } 
   catch (Utils::ProcessControl::AREException & exception) 
   { 
       throw exception; 
   } 
}
```

With the following inputs:

```
OFF 
8 12 0 

-2e+07 -2e+07 1.00006e+07 
-2e+07 2e+07 1.00008e+07 
2e+07 -2e+07 1.00001e+07 
2e+07 2e+07 1.00005e+07 
-2e+07 -2e+07 4e+07 
-2e+07 2e+07 4e+07 
2e+07 -2e+07 4e+07 
2e+07 2e+07 4e+07 
3  2 0 1 
3  3 2 1 
3  5 4 6 
3  5 6 7 
3  2 4 0 
3  2 6 4 
3  0 5 1 
3  0 4 5 
3  3 6 2 
3  3 7 6 
3  1 7 3 
3  1 5 7 


OFF 
8 12 0 

-2e+07 -2e+07 -1.99998e+07 
-2e+07 2e+07 -1.99998e+07 
2e+07 -2e+07 -1.99998e+07 
2e+07 2e+07 -1.99998e+07 
-2e+07 -2e+07 6.99999e+07 
-2e+07 2e+07 6.99999e+07 
2e+07 -2e+07 6.99999e+07 
2e+07 2e+07 6.99999e+07 
3  2 0 1 
3  3 2 1 
3  5 4 6 
3  5 6 7 
3  2 4 0 
3  2 6 4 
3  0 5 1 
3  0 4 5 
3  3 6 2 
3  3 7 6 
3  1 7 3 
3  1 5 7
```

It crashes at the first Polyhedron to Nef_polyhedron conversion launching the following assertion (in debug mode):

```
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CGAL::Assertion_exception' 
 what():  CGAL ERROR: assertion violation! 
 Expr: h.has_on(p) 
 File: /home/giorgio/Scrivania/Librerie/CGAL-4.4/include/CGAL/Nef_3/SNC_intersection.h 
 Line: 377
```

What's wrong?

Thank you, 
Giorgio

Comment: When I tried this on my end (unfortunately I have CGAL 4.3 and not 4.4), I didn't get any errors. At first I thought it was because of the kernel I used (wasn't paying too much attention and used exact predicates/exact constructions kernel), but even with simple Cartesian it runs.

Comment: Using CGAL::Homogeneous instead of CGAL::Simple_cartesian it runs so it seems to be a kernel problem (for CGAL4.4). Can you suggest what could be the reason of this kernel dependent problem?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea. But, since it works with the Cartesian kernel in 4.3, maybe a change in 4.4 made that kernel buggy in this case? Have you tried reporting this to CGAL community as a potential bug?

Comment: @DOFHandler have you worked out what was going on?  I have this very strange bug which might be related.  https://github.com/Oslandia/SFCGAL/issues/139